# How to rerender an Iframe in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make an app which allows users to build an HTML page.
The UI has two sections

1. Designer
2. Preview

The preview is inside an Iframe to create a sandboxed environment.
Whenever user changes anything in the designer, I want to rerender the preview. This makes all the input elements lag in the designer.

I am rerendering preview on onChange event of input elements of the designer.

What is the best way to overcome this problem?

Comment: Well, iframes work fine in react. You just need to maintain the state which captures the input on `Designer`, and the `iframe` should react to the state.

Comment: @wentjun 
Can you please tell me how to add child components in iframe.
Right now When I am doing like this:
`<iframe title="preview" id='iframe'>
    <body>Nihal</body>
</iframe>`

It produces DOM structure like this.
`<iframe title="preview" id="iframe">
    #document
        <html>
            <head></head>
            <body></body>
        </html>
    <html>
        <body>
            Nihal
        </body>
    </html>
</iframe>`

It does not use the iframe body, instead creates a new one.